# Amazon Lambda & API Gateway - 'event.source_ip' returns 'null'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I'm trying to grab the IP of users.

I followed guides on how to do this, and found answers that use event.source_ip in the lambda function, which connects to the API Gateway.

The result returns *'null'* in my Lex & Facebook bots, and returns *'test-invoke-source-ip'* in the API Gateway Test.

**Lambda**:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    callback(null, event.source_ip);
};
```

**API Gateway: *Integration Request***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use lambda proxy integration, then you can handle the event and context from the lamda function yourself. You can read more here. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html

You will need to return expected output for it to work.

Example using node (untested):

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
 var res = {
   "statusCode": 200,
   "body": context.identity.sourceIp,
   "isBase64Encoded": false,
 }
 callback(null, res);
}
```

Comment: To view the contents of event or context just use console.log them to view in cloudwatch logs.